# pgsql2shp "Error executing user query"

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5

I have been getting Initialization error while attempting the `pgsql2shp` postgresql code:

```
pgsql2shp -f output.shp -h localhost -u postgres -P admin parcel "SELECT * FROM 'public'.'Parcel' WHERE ParcelNoEng=116"
```

> Error : Initializing... Error executing user query: ERROR:  syntax
>   error at or near "'Parcel'" LINE 1: ...__pgsql2shp11748_tmp_table" AS
>   SELECT * FROM public.'*P*arcel'

Error error marker is italic here.

Answer (score 0):

You're using illegal characters in your SQL Statement. More specifically, in the table name `'public'.'Parcel'`, where it should be (using double quotes `"`) :

```
SELECT * FROM "public"."Parcel" WHERE ParcelNoEng=116
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM public.Parcel WHERE ParcelNoEng=116
```

or even (since we're talking about the `public` schema):

```
SELECT * FROM Parcel WHERE ParcelNoEng=116
```

Check the SQL lexical syntax [`here`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).